QGIS ignores argument "direction_range" for GRASS r.viewshed
I am trying to run the GRASS tool r.viewshed in QGIS. The GRASS tool includes an optional parameter direction_range which lets you analyse a specific horizontal angle range. In the QGIS GUI this parameter is not exposed, so I've tried scripting it using the Python scripting window within QGIS, and running:
processing.run("grass7:r.viewshed", params)

where params is a python dictionary of my input parameters, including:
direction_range='0,90'

Everything runs correctly except it ignores the direction_range argument. The output includes the full 360 degrees.
Have you had this problem, figured out the cause, and found a solution?
It works in GRASS (run separately, outside QGIS) but I really would prefer to use QGIS if possible.

The QGIS processing tool that runs r.viewshed hasn't been updated to support GRASS8 parameters and the direction_range parameter is only available in GRASS8. So you can only use GRASS itself for this. You may wish to submit an enhancement request to the QGIS team.

Thanks @user2856!
